# Can you pray too much?

Tags: final-fantasy-4

I recently acquired Rosa and have been making very frequent use of her free healing and MP restoration with Pray. It seems to have been decreasing in power as I use it, and most recently went completely unanswered. Does praying too much lessen its power or is it just random?

Comment: Which version of FF4 is this?

Comment: DS. Didn't realize it mattered. I thought the mechanics were the same.

Comment: Nope, they retooled things in the DS and iOS releases. Not as much as they did for FF3, I don't think, but significant enough, and it may be relevant regarding Pray (seeing as it was one of the skills that wasn't even in the US SNES release). Though I suppose a good answer could just give the answer to each version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original incarnations, Pray was 50% chance to cast Cure, and a 50% chance to do nothing at all.  The fact that it was just a cast of Cure made it somewhat less appealing later in the game when HP is higher and more powerful healing is possible.

[In the DS/mobile versions](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Pray_(Ability)) (which you are playing):

> Pray restores both HP and MP, the amount of which is dependent on the party member's max HP and MP, and has a higher rate of success.

Beyond the chance to fail, Pray is otherwise unlimited and no ill effects will occur from its (over)use.  Abuse away.

Comment: I never played the DS version because I had just played the GBA one and was really annoyed that all that extra content didn't make it into the DS one...so this is news to me.  Damn, it actually sounds useful like this!